# Custom adatper getView returns null pointer

Tags: android, custom-adapter, getview

In my app I have a listview with a custom adapter which is reloaded after a message was send. The app chrashes at some of the installations. I have in the app console the stack traces. Here the code:

```
class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
        Activity context;

        IconicAdapter(Activity context) {
            super(context, R.layout.message_layout, listItems);

            this.context = context;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


                //you can access layout inflater by accessing hosting activity
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.message_layout, parent, false);


            JSONObject json_data = null;
            try {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(position);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }

            try {
                tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
                tv.setText(json_data.getString("username"));
```

Here stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.testing.gold.CommunityFragment$IconicAdapter.getView (CommunityFragment.java:945)
  at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView (HeaderViewListAdapter.java:232)
```

The line 945: tv.setText(json_data.getString("username"));

Comment: probably your json_data is null ,   print the stacktrace : catch (JSONException e) {
            }

Comment: no there is nothing about json in the stacktrace

Comment: Print the json_data and also e.printstacktrace inside the catch. And put the log

Comment: The problem is that I cannot reproduce the problem on my end. I only see it in the app console and see there the trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code:
      class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Activity context;

```
IconicAdapter(Activity context) {
    super(context, R.layout.message_layout, listItems);

    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     convertView=LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.message_layout, null);
     JSONObject json_data = null;
     try {
        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(position);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
 tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);

if(json_data!=null)
   tv.setText(json_data.getString("username"));
else
   tv.setText("")
```

Comment: you are right the json_data is null. But I dont understand why. It works some time and some times not.

Comment: Hmm. Let's send me code on ankitpatidar030@gmail.com I will check for you

Answer (score 1):

```
class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
   Activity context;

   IconicAdapter(Activity context) {
    super(context, R.layout.activity_main, new Integer[]{1, 2});
    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    JSONObject json_data = null;
    try {
        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(position);
        tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        tv.setText(json_data.getString("username"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Is it important that it is running in fragment?

Comment: if you are using the adapter for the fragment  no it is not.

Comment: non static method inflate cannot be reference from static context

Comment: i have modified the code know it will work. also dont forget to vote me up